# Can we create a socket connection in native in Android?

Tags: android, sockets, android-ndk

I have googled to my knowledge and not able to get the exact information.
Can we create a socket in native layer of android. If so how to do it.

From the google i found the suggestions to create a socket in java layer and communicating to it throught the jni. But i wan to know if we can create a socket in the native itself.

I got this info from this thread "
[Android NDK limitations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658308/android-ndk-limitations)  "

Please let me know if anyone knows how to create a socket in native layer.

P.S: Please let me know if the question is not clear, for improving the same.

Regards,
SSuman185

Comment: Sure, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77098799/1831722)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes we can create the socket connections in native android.

The only thing need to be done is add INTERNET permission in the AndroidManifest.xml file even though we are using sockets in native.