# native socket only sends data on Android once closed

Tags: kotlin, sockets, android-ndk, arm, x86-64

The server is a kotlin app running on an Android 11 armeabi-v7a device. This is the relevant part of the server class:

```
class MySock :Activity() {

    private val logName : String = "ServerSocket"
    private var server: ServerSocket? = null

    var conn = Runnable {
        try {
            server = ServerSocket(8080, 8, InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1"))
            Log.d(logName, "webservice thread started in :Activity()")
            SConfig.isWS = true
            lateinit var socket: Socket
            lateinit var reader: BufferedReader
            var str: String
            while (true) {
                Log.d(logName, "about to .accept() on ${server!!.inetAddress.hostName}:${server!!.localPort}")
                socket = server!!.accept()
                reader = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()))
                str    = reader.lines().collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator())).toString()
                Log.d(logName, "content from socket: ${str}")
                if(str.startsWith("MY_MESSAGE"))
                {
                    Log.d(logName,"replying to MY_MESSAGE")
                    socket.getOutputStream().write("MESSAGE_REPLY".toByteArray())
                    socket.getOutputStream().flush()
                }
            }
            reader.close()
            socket.close()
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            SConfig.isWS = false
            Log.e(logName, "${e.message}")
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            SConfig.isWS = false
            Log.e(logName, "${e.message}")
        }
    }
    
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        Thread(conn).start()
    }
}
```

The ServerSocket is started with the app, backed by a foreground service, and is already running:

```
adb shell $ netstat -lteW
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address                                       Foreign Address                                     
State       User       Inode      
tcp6        0      0 localhost:8080                                      :::*                                                LISTEN      u0_a131    136667
```

Why does it insist on using IPv6 instead of v4 is a mistery, but apparently that's not an issue.
The client is a native NDK app.

I created a simple C socket client in the x86_64 GNU/Linux VM i use to develop:

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main()
{
  int status, bytesSent, bytesRead, client_fd;
  struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
  char msg1[] = "hello1";
  char buffer[1024] = "";
  bool isOpen = false;

  errno = 0;

  client_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  if (client_fd < 0) 
  {
    printf("KO: opening socket: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    goto byebyesocket;
  }
  printf("OK: socket opened, fd %d\n", client_fd);
  isOpen = true;

  serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  serv_addr.sin_port   = htons(8080);
  if (inet_pton(AF_INET, "127.0.0.1", &serv_addr.sin_addr) <= 0) 
  {
    printf("KO: converting localhost address: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    goto byebyesocket;
  }
  
  status = connect(client_fd, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
  if (status < 0) 
  {
    printf("KO: connecting: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    goto byebyesocket;
  }
  printf("OK: socket connected (%d)\n", status);

  bytesSent = send(client_fd, msg1, strlen(msg1), 0);
  if (bytesSent < 0) 
  {
    printf("KO: sending data: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    goto byebyesocket;
  }
  bytesRead = read(client_fd, buffer, 1024);
  if (bytesRead < 0) 
  {
    printf("KO: reading data: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    goto byebyesocket;
  }
  printf("OK: received '%s'\n", buffer);

byebyesocket:
  if (isOpen && 0 != close(client_fd))
  {
    printf("KO: closing socket: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    return -1;
  }
  printf("OK: socket closed\n");
  return 0;
}
```

...and tested it with this C socket server:

```
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main()
{
  int server_fd, new_socket, bytesRead, bytesSent;
  struct sockaddr_in address;
  int opt = 1;
  int addrSize = sizeof(address);
  char msg1[] = "olleh1";
  char buffer[1024] = "";

  errno = 0;
  
  server_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  if (server_fd < 0) 
  {
    printf("KO: opening socket: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    return -1;
  }
  printf("OK: socket opened, fd %d\n", server_fd);

  if (setsockopt(server_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR | SO_REUSEPORT, &opt, sizeof(opt)) != 0) 
  {
    printf("KO: calling setsockopt: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    return -1;
  }

  address.sin_family      = AF_INET;
  address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
  address.sin_port        = htons(8080);

  if (bind(server_fd, (struct sockaddr*)&address, sizeof(address)) < 0) 
  {
    printf("KO: failed to bind: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    return -1;
  }
  printf("OK: bound\n");

  if (listen(server_fd, 3) < 0) 
  {
    printf("KO: failed to listen: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    return -1;
  }
  printf("OK: listening\n");
  
  new_socket = accept(server_fd, (struct sockaddr*)&address, (socklen_t*)&addrSize);
  if (new_socket < 0) {
    printf("KO: failed to accept: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    return -1;
  }

  bytesRead = read(new_socket, buffer, 1024);
  if (bytesRead < 0) 
  {
    printf("error reading data: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    return -1;
  }
  printf("received data: %s, replying with %s\n", buffer, msg1);

  bytesSent = send(new_socket, msg1, strlen(msg1), 0);
  if (bytesSent < 0) 
  {
    printf("error sending data: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    return -1;
  }
  printf("OK: data sent\n");

  if (0 != close(new_socket))
  {
    printf("KO: failed to close: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    return -1;
  }
  if (0 != shutdown(server_fd, SHUT_RDWR))
  {
    printf("KO: failed to shutdown: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    return -1;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

works as expected:

```
// server output
OK: socket opened, fd 3
OK: bound
OK: listening
received data: hello1, replying with olleh1
OK: data sent

// client output
OK: socket opened, fd 3
OK: socket connected (0)
OK: received 'olleh1'
OK: socket closed
```

The client app uses 127.0.0.1:8080 elsewhere in the code to *send* data to the server socket on multiple occasions and that's working fine.
However i now need it to also *receive* (in this example "MESSAGE_REPLY") and this is where i'm encountering problems.

When including the client code in the native app:

```
#if defined(__ANDROID__)
    {
      int status = 0, bytesSent = 0, bytesRead = 0, client_fd;
      struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
      char msg1[] = "MY_MESSAGE";
      char buffer[1024] = "";
      bool isOpen = false;

      errno = 0;

      client_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
      if (client_fd < 0)
      {
        printf("KO: opening socket: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        goto byebyesocket;
      }
      printf("OK: socket opened, fd %d\n", client_fd);
      isOpen = true;

      serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
      serv_addr.sin_port   = htons(8080);
      if (inet_pton(AF_INET, "127.0.0.1", &serv_addr.sin_addr) <= 0)
      {
        printf("KO: converting localhost address: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        goto byebyesocket;
      }

      status = connect(client_fd, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
      if (status < 0)
      {
        printf("KO: connecting: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        goto byebyesocket;
      }
      printf("OK: socket connected (%d)\n", status);


      bytesSent = send(client_fd, msg1, strlen(msg1), 0);
      if (bytesSent < 0)
      {
        printf("KO: sending data: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        goto byebyesocket;
      }
      bytesRead = recv(client_fd, buffer, 1024, 0);
      if (bytesRead < 0)
      {
        printf("KO: reading data: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        goto byebyesocket;
      }
      printf("OK: received '%s'\n", buffer);

byebyesocket:
      if (isOpen && 0 != close(client_fd))
      {
        printf("KO: closing socket: %s\n", strerror(errno));
      }
      printf("OK: socket closed\n");
    }
#endif
```

I get this:

```
2023-09-13 15:28:22.070 com.my.kotlin.app: webservice thread started in :Activity()
2023-09-13 15:28:22.079 com.my.kotlin.app: about to .accept() on localhost:8080
2023-09-13 15:29:45.645 com.my.native.app: OK: socket opened, fd 89
2023-09-13 15:29:45.648 com.my.native.app: OK: socket connected (0)
```

The client just hangs and won't send "MY_MESSAGE" until i terminate the app (and the socket is closed). Only then does the server receive data but there's no longer a socket to receive it at the client.

```
2023-09-13 15:30:18.028 com.my.kotlin.app: content from socket: MY_MESSAGE
2023-09-13 15:30:18.029 com.my.kotlin.app: replying to MY_MESSAGE
2023-09-13 15:30:18.035 com.my.kotlin.app: about to .accept() on localhost:8080
```

It'll then return to listening:

```
$ netstat -lteW                                                                                                                                                                                                              
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address                                       Foreign Address                                     
State       User       Inode      
tcp6       0      0 localhost:8080                                      :::*                                                LISTEN      u0_a131    137078
```

---

Next i tried a non-blocking socket by changing the client socket to:

```
client_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM|SOCK_NONBLOCK, 0);
```

and added

```
status = 1;
if(-1 == setsockopt(client_fd, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, (void *)&status, sizeof(status)))
{
  printf("KO: setting TCP_NODELAY");
}
```

as a way to work around buffering (and Nagle?). Adding `SOCK_NONBLOCK` was enough for the server to react:

```
2023-09-13 15:41:11.325 com.my.native.app: OK: socket opened, fd 85
2023-09-13 15:41:11.328 com.my.native.app: KO: connecting: Operation now in progress
2023-09-13 15:41:11.328 com.my.native.app: OK: socket closed
2023-09-13 15:41:11.336 com.my.kotlin.app: content from socket: 
2023-09-13 15:41:11.338 com.my.kotlin.app: about to .accept() on localhost:8080
```

but predictabily the client socket closed. So i used epoll, changing my test client, which worked with my test server:

```
// server
OK: socket opened, fd 3
OK: bound
OK: listening
received data: MY_REQUEST, replying with olleh1
OK: data sent

// client
OK: socket opened, fd 3
OK: epoll configured
OK: socket connected (0)
OK: socket connected!
OK: sent 10 bytes
OK: socket 3 has data
OK: received 'olleh1'
OK: socket closed
```

and implementing it in the native app:

```
#if defined(__ANDROID__)
{
  int status, client_fd, num_ready, i = 1;
  struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
  char buffer[1024] = "";
  int isOpen = 0;
  struct epoll_event events[64];
  int epfd = 0;
  struct epoll_event event;
  char* request = "MY_REQUEST";
  int   reqlen  = strlen(request);
  int   reqsent = 0;

  errno = 0;

  client_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  if (client_fd < 0) 
  {
    printf("KO: opening socket: %s", strerror(errno));
    goto byebyesocket;
  }
  printf("OK: socket opened, fd %d", client_fd);
  isOpen = 1;

  serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  serv_addr.sin_port   = htons(8080);
  if (inet_pton(AF_INET, "127.0.0.1", &serv_addr.sin_addr) <= 0) 
  {
    printf("KO: converting localhost address: %s", strerror(errno));
    goto byebyesocket;
  }

  if (-1 == setsockopt(client_fd, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, (void *)&i, sizeof(i)))
  {
    printf("KO: setting setsockopt: %s", strerror(errno));
    goto byebyesocket;
  }

  epfd = epoll_create(1);
  if (-1 == epfd)
  {
    printf("KO: calling epoll_create: %s", strerror(errno));
    goto byebyesocket;
  }
  event.events  = EPOLLIN;
  event.data.fd = client_fd;
  if (0 != epoll_ctl(epfd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, client_fd, &event))
  {
    printf("KO: calling epoll_ctl: %s", strerror(errno));
    goto byebyesocket;
  }
  printf("OK: epoll configured");
  
  status = connect(client_fd, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
  if (status < 0) 
  {
    printf("KO: connecting: %s", strerror(errno));
    goto byebyesocket;
  }
  printf("OK: socket connected (%d)", status);

  num_ready = epoll_wait(epfd, events, 64, 1000/*timeout*/);
  for (i = 0; i < num_ready; i++) 
  {
    if (events[i].events & EPOLLIN) 
    {
      printf("OK: socket connected"); // never gets printer
    }
  }
  printf("OK: socket connected!"); 

  i = -1;
  while(i != 0 && reqsent < reqlen)
  {
    i = send(client_fd, request, strlen(request), 0);
    printf("OK: sent %d bytes", i);
    if(i == -1) 
    {
      printf("KO: send error: %s", strerror(errno));
      goto byebyesocket;
    }
    reqsent += i;
  }
  printf("OK: data send, waiting for reply...");

  num_ready = epoll_wait(epfd, events, 64, 5000/*timeout*/);
  for (i = 0; i < num_ready; i++) 
  {
    if (events[i].events & EPOLLIN) 
    {
      printf("OK: socket %d has data", events[i].data.fd);
      bzero(buffer, 1024);
      recv(client_fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
      printf("OK: received '%s'", buffer);
    }
  }

byebyesocket:
  if (1 == isOpen && 0 != close(client_fd))
  {
    printf("KO: closing socket: %s", strerror(errno));
  }
  printf("OK: socket closed");
}
#endif
```

But the behavior is the same:

```
2023-09-13 16:44:27.120 com.my.native.app OK: socket opened, fd 80
2023-09-13 16:44:27.120 com.my.native.app OK: epoll configured
2023-09-13 16:44:27.123 com.my.native.app OK: socket connected (0)
2023-09-13 16:44:28.124 com.my.native.app OK: socket connected!
2023-09-13 16:44:28.125 com.my.native.app OK: sent 10 bytes
2023-09-13 16:44:28.125 com.my.native.app OK: data sent, waiting for reply...
2023-09-13 16:44:33.131 com.my.native.app OK: socket closed
2023-09-13 16:44:33.148 com.my.kotlin.app content from socket: MY_REQUEST
2023-09-13 16:44:33.148 com.my.kotlin.app replying to GET_BT_DEVICES
2023-09-13 16:44:33.157 com.my.kotlin.app about to .accept() on localhost:8080
```

The data is only sent after the 5s delay expires and the socket is closed.

The test clients/server work on GNU/Linux x86_64 and both apps have been working just fine for ages (since communication was one-way only), yet when on Android armeabi-v7a the behavior changes.

I'm unsure why. I could just spawn a server socket on the client but would rather grok this.

---

Edit: i tried adding a `\n` to the message but i don't think that'd help anyway. I also have `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` in the manifest.